# better way to write If statement with a lot of repeats in rails ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, for-loop

I have a table with 30 different columns and I am trying to write a method that calls on each column containing a value.

eg.

```
def add_details 
customer = Customer.find self.customer_id 
if self.room1.present? && self.room2.present? && self.room3.present? && self.room4.present? && self.room5.present?  && self.room6.present? && self.room7.present?  && self.room8.present? && self.room9.present? && self.room10.present? && self.room11.present? && self.room12.present? && self.room13.present? && self.room14.present? && self.room15.present?  && self.room16.present? && self.room17.present?  && self.room18.present? && self.room19.present? && self.room20.present? && self.room21.present? && self.room22.present? && self.room23.present? && self.room24.present? && self.room25.present?  && self.room26.present? && self.room27.present?  && self.room28.present? && self.room29.present? && self.room30.present? 

elsif self.room.present? && self.room2.present? && self.room3.present? && self.room4.present? && self.room5.present?  && self.room6.present? && self.room7.present?  && self.room8.present? && self.room9.present? && self.room10.present? && self.room11.present? && self.room12.present? && self.room13.present? && self.room14.present? && self.room15.present?  && self.room16.present? && self.room17.present?  && self.room18.present? && self.room19.present? && self.room20.present? && self.room21.present? && self.room22.present? && self.room23.present? && self.room24.present? && self.room25.present?  && self.room26.present? && self.room27.present?  && self.room28.present? && self.room29.present? 
  room = Room.find self.room
  .....
  room29 = ... end end
```

This is a whole lot of repeating myself and I know ruby is dynamic so there should be a way to increment the numbers with like a for loop and it would still work. I dont know if anyone has a better way to write this

Comment: Why do you have 30 room columns in a table? This _reeks_ of suboptimal design.

Comment: I wont mind an alternative... was due to deadline but definitely know thats not the right way to do a booking system... what i had before was just to book 1 room but needed to add booking multiple rooms up to 30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Options 1: Assume that all model attributes need to validate

```
validate_needed_columns = Model.attribute_names
while validate_needed_columns.present? do
  if validate_needed_columns.all?{ |c| Model[c].present? }
    Model.update_columns(<Hash here>)
    break
  end

  validate_needed_columns.pop
end
```

## Options 2: Use mapping to set which columns need to update

```
validate_needed_columns = {
  column_name_1: value_to_update_1,
  ...
  column_name_n: value_to_update_n
}
validate_needed_column_keys = validate_needed_columns.keys
while validate_needed_column_keys.present? do
  if validate_needed_column_keys.all?{ |c| Model[c].present? }
    Model.update_columns(<Use mapping to set value here>)
    break
  end

  validate_needed_column_keys.pop
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do something like this:

```
if (up_to_29 = (1..29).all?{|i| send("column#{i}").present? }) && column30.present?
  # update_columns column1: ...
elsif up_to_29
  # update_columns column1: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range of numbers to loop through and call `"column_#{i}"` on each one. The `all?` method will return true if every iteration of the loop is true. Try something like this:

```
if (1..30).all?{|index| self.send("column#{index}")&.present? }
  #...
elsif (1..29).all?{|index| self.send("column#{index}")&.present? }
  #...
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)